# Dynamic Object to access Database C#

Tags: c#, dynamic

Can i use a dynamic C# object to access database values. For example if i have a table name Settings, with different values could i simply call from code Settings.SomeSetting, rather then programming them all.

Comment: What is it that you call a dynamic object? Worst case you can simply save the setting to a text file and load them for example...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a C# ORM in order to do something like what you are trying to do.

[Dapper.Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) - A simple C# ORM.
[NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) - A mature ORM which has been around while.

I don't have experience with either but both sound like something you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [blog post showing one technique using a dynamic wrapper for ADO.NET data access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/10/29/using-c-dynamic-to-simplify-ado-net-use.aspx).  This should work against a query run against an Access database (as well as any other ADO.NET data source).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Probably you will get insane later, but you can. Also, if you want to access the data in a reflective way and without compilation check, you could just use DataSets. They suck, but... You are about to reinvent the weel.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Simple.Data](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data). It sounds like what you're looking for.